# Where can I find the list of all Java (SE 7) standard library classes which have methods which will throw an EOFException?

Tags: java, exception, java-7, ioexception, eofexception

I'm trying to track down the source of an `EOFException` in some client/server code, but many of the classes used only have methods which say that they throw an `IOException`, not specifically an `EOFException`. Normally I'd just look at the stack trace but I don't have it and can't reproduce it. So, it would be helpful to have a list of every class which has methods which throw `EOFException` specifically, but I don't know how to find out this information.

Is there a source of information on every (standard) Java class (in SE 7, in my case) which has methods which throw `EOFException`? I have tried reading the Javadocs on [`EOFException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html) to no avail.

(I have found, at least, that [`DataInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html) does mention`EOFException`. But are there any more?)

*Afterword:* Since it seems the only way to find out is to inspect the source code, [here](http://pastebin.com/zZJYbYfR) is the result of me searching for "`EOFException`" in the extracted source code (1.7.0_45).

Comment: Download the source for the core java libraries, create a project for them, do a search in the project using your IDE of choice.

Comment: Basically any stream class could throw this.

Comment: @TimB Is this the only way?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

Comment: An EOFException means that a file or stream ended prematurely - knowing where that came from exactly in the libraries is much less important than knowing what data was read (especially since you could then replicate the issue).

Comment: @Njol It's hard for me to reproduce the issue in this case without knowing which part of the code is actually reading this data. In fact, it's hard for me to reproduce the issue at all, since in my particular circumstances I don't know how to run some of the system under question. Long story short, I am trying to reproduce this with a unit test, not functionally.

Comment: This question should really be "all Java standard library classes" instead of just "all clases". As soon as someone gives you a complete list of all classes, I could just write another one.

Comment: @Ingo Okay, you know what I mean...

Comment: @John You're right, I will edit.

Comment: Note: javadoc, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/class-use/EOFException.html does not help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** *Added results for 7.51, for all source code in the JDK, at the bottom.*

In Java 6.17, here are all classes that explicitly throw `java.io.EOFException`. Specifically, it is the number of times `new\s+EOFException` was found in each source-code file.

```
java.io.DataInputStream.java: 8
java.io.ObjectInputStream.java: 6
java.io.RandomAccessFile.java: 8
java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.java: 2
java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.java: 1
java.util.zip.ZipFile.java: 1
java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.java: 1
```

Here is another bit of information: All source-code files containing `catch\s*\(\s*EOFException`:

```
java.io.ObjectInputStream.java: 1
java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.java: 1
```

Note that there are no standard `java.*` Exception classes that extend `EOFException` (there are no occurances of

```
extends\s+([a-z]+\.)*EOFException
```

anywhere in the `java.*` source-code).

This is a limited but valuable ***starting point***. As mentioned by others, there may be situations that this misses--when all you have is the source-code to work from, it will be time-consuming to find them. Hopefully this information will set you down the right path.

---

Here are the results for Java 7.51, for *all* source-code provided with the JDK:

`extends\s+([a-z]+\.)*EOFException`

*none*

`catch\s*\(\s*EOFException`

```
com.sun.imageio.plugins.gif.GIFImageReader: 1
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl: 1
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl: 4
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector: 1
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDLoader: 2
java.io.ObjectInputStream: 1
java.util.zip.ZipInputStream: 1
```

`new\s+EOFException`

```
com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream: 1
com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader: 1
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl: 1
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager: 1
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner: 1
java.io.DataInputStream: 8
java.io.ObjectInputStream: 6
java.io.RandomAccessFile: 8
java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream: 2
java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream: 1
java.util.zip.ZipFile: 1
java.util.zip.ZipInputStream: 1
javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl: 8
```

Comment: (Why are you still using Java 6?  Why are you using an old version of Java 6?  :-) )

Comment: Good answer, no upvote though as you don't say how you got the information.

Comment: This misses a number of methods in other classes, such as in java.util.jar.JarInputStream

Comment: In 6.17, there are no occurances of `EOFException` in `java.util.jar.*`.

Comment: When I searched the SE 7 source code using that name regex I also found `javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl` (though it is abstract), as well as `com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream`, `com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader`, `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl`, `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager`, and `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner`. The others in your list were also present.

Comment: @aliteralmind But this doesn't mean that you can read from a JarInputStream without having to be prepared for EOFException.

Comment: Of course. This information is limited. It's only searching for regexes in the source code. It's a *starting point*, not a perfect reflective analysis.

Comment: @2rs2ts Yes, I only searched `java.*`, not `javax.*` or `com.sun.*`.

Comment: @aliteralmind Of course. I thought I'd be thorough for anyone reading this later. Those packages don't apply in my case anyway.

Comment: FWIW I should also add that [`ImageInputStreamImpl`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/stream/ImageOutputStreamImpl.html) has a few subclasses. I am not going to bother figuring out whether they override the methods which throw `EOFException` in `ImageOutputStreamImpl` and then do not throw `EOFException` in those methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can find that out only under the assumption that the code creates and immediately throws an EOFException. But the follwoing could also throw an EOFException:

```
class Foo {
    ...
    public void iAmHarmless(Exception x) { if (x != null) throw x; }
    ...
 }
```

Or how about the follwoing, to defeat aliteralminds method:

```
 class XYException extends EOFException { ... }
 class Foo {
     public void surprise() { throw new XYException().super(); }
 }
```

Joking aside - methods from many classes may throw EOFException simply because of inheritance. A grep for "EOFException" gives only the very base classes. But you must consider all subclasses thereof. Example: `java.util.jar.JarInputStream`

Comment: In this case, the Javadocs do not mention a subclass of `EOFException`. Do you think the implementation of the Java standard libraries is really going to do something like that?

Comment: It is but 2 possible ways to conceal throwing of EOFExceptions I immediatly saw. Another one is inheritance. When you look at the short list in aliteralminds answer, you'll notice.

Comment: @2rs2ts explained the inheritance problem.

Comment: Of course. If I have to compile this list myself by examining the source code, then it's implicit that if a superclass has a method which throws `EOFException`, then any subclass which does not override the method(s) in question, or does so but also throws an `EOFException` in its own implementation, will also be part of the list.